# Problems tracking down network "stability" issue roots

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, asynchttpclient

I got app which does some networking based on user activity. Usual payload sent by the app is 100-200 bytes so basically no heavy lifting tasks. These tasks are usually working w/o any problems (statistically 99,9% or requests are fine), but aside from these networking activities, my app is also sending heartbeat back to our servers (which are on Amazon's EC2 (us-east1-d if that would matter)). Heartbeat is sent each 10 seconds as ordinary POST request over HTTPS - and this is what is not really working for me as the failure rate is much higher than observed with normal network activities - during my recent 7 hour test 25% of heartbeat requests failed (but I saw even 35% drops) and it usually keeps at that rate. When I disable SSL then error rate stays on my test device at 8% percent. This probably would not be that big issue really if these failures would fall into any pattern (i.e. each 4th etc which could mean some rate based filtering, or would fail close to each full hour or day which could mean kind of request cap is set somewhere). But nothing like this happens - sometimes 10-15 request can fail in a row, and this is bad for heartbeat. Additionally, to make thing worse, at the moment I see requests failing I can connect to the server from the same device and this is working without problems). This issue happens on any supported version of Android (2.2+).

I use recent [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) to do the HTTP requests, so I started to suspect that lib to be a culprit so I switched to [Android Asynchronous HTTP Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) but it gave no change really. I am mostly getting Exceptions like:

> NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond The
>   target server failed to respond URL: https://xx.xx.xx.xx/heartbeat/

and for SSL enabled connections also:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x784bc588: I/O error
>   during system call, Connection reset by peer Read error:
>   ssl=0x784bc588: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
>   URL: https://xx.xx.xx.xx/heartbeat/

I basically would like to trace the culprit first, so knowing that the app is running over mobile networks mostly, I am open for any suggestion to how to proceed further with this problem as I am at the moment stuck a bit.

Comment: Have you fully checked your server's performance?

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" this is probably a server issue. To make it clear you may trace it with WireShark maybe. http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Your new choice of library has interesting issues: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues

Answer (score 0):

Run this app and just do a normal ping to see the error rate: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ulfdittmer.android.ping

Run it on both mobile network (cellular) and WiFi.

If you are on WiFi, run `ping -n 100 google.com` from a laptop to verify your router and network access point are not flaky. If so, unplug the router and plug it back in. Linksys routers and access points and Belkin access points get flaky like that.

If you need a 10s heartbeat, set the HTTP timeout to 3-5 seconds and fail fast, and retry if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you share your HttpClient instance across the hearthbeat thread and ui thread, the regular http connection request might cancel the one on progress. Please be sure that they do not send request at the same time, either by locking the object or seperating HttpClient instances.